# Idea 3 of 3: Badge inventor badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

For people whose badge ideas get implemented.
Because new good badges are good for the SO site.

Comment: Do you get a badge if this badge idea gets implemented?

Comment: Maybe, I don't set the rules.

Comment: I want a Recursion badge... awarded for receiving the Recursion badge.

Comment: Tautology badge. Indicates user has received tautology badge.

Comment: how would this even work? the badge suggestion would only be made on meta, so would the badge only be given on meta? or would it be given to the user on every site it is implemented on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Awarding badges manually rather than automatically through an algorithm is going to be prone to chaos, confusion, and a bureaucratic nightmare for the site maintainers.  Currently the only such badge is "Hacker", which is being reserved for exceptional circumstances and still has not yet been awarded.

The current reward for suggesting a good idea is **increased reputation on Meta Stack Overflow**. That reputation is visible on the other SOFU sites in everyone's user profile under the "Accounts" tab. I don't see a need to extend the recognition beyond that; if badges were awarded, many Meta regulars would want to be given this badge retroactively as recognition for their ideas that have been implemented.

Comment: OK, agree. Thanks for pointing to accounts tab thing.

Answer (score 4):

To be very frank, meta gets an pretty heavy stream of badge suggestions as it is (in fact at one point the mods closed all the various individual badge suggestions and made a unified questions to hold them all), and most of them are not so hot. A few are decent, a few really suck, and the really great ones are few and far between.

This suggestions would magnify the scale of the sorting problem by encouraging an endless stream of suggestions.

BTW--As I count it there are 44 existing badge separate of the specialist ones (admittedly there are several groups: [nice|good|great], [notable|popular|famous] and so on). We don't lack for either numbers of diversity of requirements. So we can afford to be picky.

Comment: I agree. That's why really good badge ideas are rare, even less gets implemented, so why not reward it? Meta is created for suggestions, let's not limit it. Good ideas will be up-voted, bad ideas - down-voted, so the number should not be a problem.

Comment: Because we don't want to wade through a bjillion repeats of "Badge for accepting answers" and "Badge for getting answers accepted" and "Badge for a lot of downvotes" and "Badge for a contraversial post" and "Badge for reopeneing" and "Badge for having you post closed and reopened N times" and "Badge for navel gazing" and and and

Comment: @ dmckee: If something has potential problems it doesn't mean that it has to be rejected outright. It just means that those issues has to be thought about and accounted for. Basically you listed two problems that SO faces every day: bad and duplicate questions. And yet SO successfully exists. Because there are ways to deal with it. To minimize bad badge suggestions it should be **clearly stated**, that good badge is a badge that promotes good behavior on the site.