# Badge suggestion: Badger

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idea 3 of 3: Badge inventor badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/idea-3-of-3-badge-inventor-badge)

The Meta-only silver Badger  badge would be awarded when a user's badge request is implemented.

Why, no, this is not self-serving at all.  I'm sure I have no idea what you mean, sir.

Comment: The double-entendre is what makes the badge name all the more hilarious.

Comment: This has been suggested several times, but I'm failing at finding any now

Comment: @Michael Number 2 on the related list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/idea-3-of-3-badge-inventor-badge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mushroom! Mushroom!