# Badge Request Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idea 3 of 3: Badge inventor badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/idea-3-of-3-badge-inventor-badge)

This might sound a little dumb but what about a badge that you get when you suggest a badge that gets implated or a idea gets implated. The badge could be silver/gold and you could get it more than once so you can think more ideas.

(The pic of the badge idea is coming to a cinema soon!)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/idea-3-of-3-badge-inventor-badge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this would result in a load of badge requests. Not sure if we want that.

Comment: Yes but only ones that has been made a real badge.

Comment: @Benny but if there was a badge reward for suggesting a badge that gets made into one, you'd see an increase in badge suggestions