# Badge for making a feature request that gets implemented?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idea 3 of 3: Badge inventor badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/idea-3-of-3-badge-inventor-badge)

Basically if someone asks a question that the SO team determines is worthy of an update to the site, then a badge would be awarded.

Seems fitting for the meta site...

Comment: You mean feature request that leads to such feature really implemented?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: Sounds like it would be difficult to do retroactively.  Edit: Because checking for both feature-request/status completed tags is super complicated.  /facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar already exists and there are currently 30 people who have attained the rather lofty requirements:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/86/status-completed

Comment: This is not true. The badge counts answers too, so I could get it without every proposing anything.

Comment: @Kop Many features are implemented according to the answers that were generated from the initial request.  But you are right that it's not exactly what this person is requesting, however it's very relevant, and may be the closest we can get to such a badge.